# receive push notification while app is killed by swiping

Tags: android

I am trying to implement push notification in my app which is receiving notification while it is in foreground and background but as i swipe  it away from tray it doesn't receive notification.What should be the solution for this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve... Also provide a full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a `Service` for this.
Services are the long running tasks which are functional even after the app is killed.

Here are some tutorials on services

[Tutorial 1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html)

[Tutorial 2](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-service-tutorial)

[Android developer's Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)